# AVPlayer doesn't call play() in background mode in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I try to handle loop audio in my app. I use AVPlayer to play mp3 file and handle loop. That work perfectly when app active. In the background mode, It doesn't work.

I try to handle loop by this function which work perfectly in active mode. When I tap home and switch to background mode, the music play to the end and loop video is called. This function print `afffffffff` but `videoPlayer?.play()` is not work.

```
func loopVideo(videoPlayer: AVPlayer, index: Int) {
        currentSoundIDs[index]["observer"] = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak videoPlayer] _ in
            videoPlayer?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            print("afffffffff")
            videoPlayer?.play()
        }
    }
```

I want to make `videoPlayer?.play()` work in background or the solution to handle loop with AVPlayer in both background and active mode. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try enabling the option `Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture` in `Background Mode` configuration yet?

Ref:
[Enabling Background Audio](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/enabling_background_audio)

Comment: I have already configured and app has still worked fine for music is on duration time on background mode. When the music finished, it didn't call ```videoPlayer?.play()``` to play music again on background mode

Comment: @MinhTâmNguyễn Could you add an observer, to detect when the audio playing reaches near the end of the audio file, to start a new audio file, or just start the current audio file again? Like 5 sec before the audio ends.
Cuz, your app can be suspended when audio playing ends, it could not run the function "play()", through the print("") still get called.